# http-proxy-rules not serving images & other resources

Tags: node.js, static, http-status-code-404, http-proxy

1. I have a node js app (port 10002) and an angular-js(port 10003) app deployed using pm2. All good when you specify port using colon(:) like host:10003
2. For some reason I had to create a nodejs proxy using http-proxy and http-proxy-rules to forward 10001 to 10002 OR 10003 like this:

```html
var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
HttpProxyRules = require('http-proxy-rules');

// Set up proxy rules instance
var proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
rules: {
'.*/api': 'http://localhost:10002/api', // Rule (1)
'.*/': 'http://localhost:10003/' // Rule (2)
},
default: 'http://localhost:10003' // default target
});

// Create reverse proxy instance
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxy();

// Create http server that leverages reverse proxy instance
// and proxy rules to proxy requests to different targets
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

// a match method is exposed on the proxy rules instance
// to test a request to see if it matches against one of the specified rules
console.log(req.url);
var target = proxyRules.match(req);
if (target) {
return proxy.web(req, res, {
  target: target
});
}

res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('The request url and path did not match any of the listed rules!');
}).listen(process.env.PROXYPORT || 10001);
```

As you can see I copied exact same code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-rules

Problem:

When the angular js app is accessed using actual port like http://host:10003, I can see images. But when I use the proxy port http://host:10001, which takes me to port 10003, **everything works except the static images, css, etc.**

Appreciate any help on this please.

Answer (score 0):

That was a silly mistake, in case anyone else hit the same problem, here is the solution, remove .* from the filter as this:

```html
// Set up proxy rules instance
var proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
rules: {
'/api': 'http://localhost:10002/api', // Rule (1)
'/': 'http://localhost:10003/' // Rule (2)
},
default: 'http://localhost:10003' // default target
});
```